# How to import ssl wildcard cert from Apache to Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl

I currently have a wildcard certificate from Comodo that is currently used for Apache. I need to use this for Confluence, running on Tomcat. I tried following their instructions, but realized that I need to import the current cert using the keytool command to get it to the right format.

I currently have the following files from Comodo:

```
filename.ca-bundle
filename.crt
filename.key
```

Has anyone been able to convert the certificate to work on Tomcat and if so, can you point to the documentation used? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to use certificate for enabling SSL on Tomcat, or you want to use the certificate for trusting another application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. Need to convert to PKCS12, then to JKS.

To convert to PKCS12:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in <filename.crt> -inkey <filename.key> -out <filename.pkcs12> -name tomcat -CAfile <filename.ca-bundle> -caname root
```

Make note of the password entered as you will need it for the next step.

To convert from PKCS12 to JKS:

```
./keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass <some_password> -destkeypass <some_password> -destkeystore <filename.jks> -srckeystore <filename.pkcs12> -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass <password_entered_previously> -alias tomcat
```

Comment: Thanks mate, your tip is awesome. it worked very well!